# What is the difference between “pad out to“ and “pad out with”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I have read an article that says;

> *We then have to **pad out** the JPEG header **to** the length of 0x2F2A **with** nulls*

but in my mind, it should be

> *We then have to **pad out** the JPEG header **with** the length of 0x2F2A **using** nulls*

Comment: how long should the header be? 0x2f2a, or header length + ox2f2a?

Comment: He padded the novel out to 320 pages with 24 pages of historical background.

Answer (score 1):

The jpeg already has a length, so it needs to be padded out TO a specified length by adding nulls to what's already there.

Comment: Padded out *with* nulls *to* the correct length in fact.

Comment: @Xanne may you give an example for that??